# multiple zones in single file, nsupdate and "ignoring out-of-zone data" as result

Tags: bind

I have magic zone file in my bind 9.7 for three identical zones:

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
 20141010222676
 3H              ; refresh
 15M             ; retry
 1W              ; expiry
 1D )            ; minimum
     IN NS ns1
     IN NS ns2
ns1  IN A  1.2.3.4
ns2  IN A  1.2.3.4
www  IN A  10.20.30.40
```

and this zones in named.conf with single file:

```
zone "zone1.tld" IN {
 type master;
 file "zone.tld";
};
zone "zone2.tld" IN {
 type master;
 file "zone.tld";
};
zone "zone3.tld" IN {
 type master;
 file "zone.tld";
};
```

I enable global nsupdate access in named.conf:

```
allow-update {
 key "key_name";
};
```

after updating via nsupdate any of this zones (e.g. zone1.tld) and stopping bind I got zone file like this:

```
$TTL 86400
zone1.tld. IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
 20141010222676
 3H              ; refresh
 15M             ; retry
 1W              ; expiry
 1D )            ; minimum
     IN NS ns1
     IN NS ns2
ns1  IN A  1.2.3.4
ns2  IN A  1.2.3.4
www  IN A  10.20.30.40
```

zone2 and zone3 is still uses this file as zone, but there is no data in this file for zone2 and zone3. bind obviously can't start, returning error "ignoring out-of-zone data".

which is the correct way to maintain several zones with fully identical data, but with possibility to use nsupdate to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as one of bind developers [replied to my question](http://marc.info/?l=bind-users&m=141345933315113) there is no solution for this issue. dynamic zones should be maintained by separate files.